NestJS how to use Sesion with RedisStore using Fastify?
I have installed NestJS v.10.3.9, Fastify v.4.28.0, @fastify/secure-session v7.5.1 and @fastify/redis v6.2.0 because I need pernament session to save tokens (id tokens/refresh tokens) to protect authentication against abuse and actions related to other users accounts.
I tried using the code below, but I kept getting a type error, which prevented me from compiling the Nest application.
Code:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import secureSession from '@fastify/secure-session';
import fastifyRedis from '@fastify/redis';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );

  const configService: ConfigService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const fastifyInstance = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
  fastifyInstance
    .addHook('onRequest', async (req, res) => {
      req.socket['encrypted'] =
        configService.get<string>('NODE_ENV', '') === 'production';
      res.header('X-Powered-By', 'CyberSecurity');
    })
    .decorateReply('setHeader', (name: string, value: unknown) => {
      this.header(name, value);
    })
    .decorateReply('end', () => {
      this.send('');
    });
  const port = configService.get<string>('PORT', '');

  await app.register(
    fastifyRedis as Parameters<NestFastifyApplication['register']>[0],
    {
      host: configService.get<string>('REDIS_HOST', ''),
      port: configService.get<string>('REDIS_PORT', ''),
      password: configService.get<string>('REDIS_PASSWORD', ''),
    },
  );

  await app.register(
    secureSession as Parameters<NestFastifyApplication['register']>[0],
    {
      sessionName: configService.get<string>('SESSION_NAME', ''),
      cookieName: configService.get<string>('SESSION_COOKIE', ''),
      expiry: configService.get<string>('SESSION_EXPIRATION_TIME', ''),
      cookie: {
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: configService.get<string>('NODE_ENV') === 'production',
      },
      secret: configService.get<string>('SESSION_SECRET', ''),
      salt: configService.get<string>('SESSION_SALT', ''),
      store: {
        type: 'redis',
        options: {
          client: app.redis,
        },
      },
    },
  );

  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();

I expected that after configuring Redis and Sessions, the application would compile normally and create a session for me.
Error:
src/main.ts:89:23 - error TS2339: Property 'redis' does not exist on type 'NestFastifyApplication<RawServerDefault>'.

89           client: app.redis,

